# Encoding of Finnish characters in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, encoding, windows-phone

I am writing a Windows Phone application and got stuck on an encoding problem.

I have created a Excel spreadsheet and exported it to a tab delimited file so that the content in the file I add as a resource to Visual Studio looks like this

```
1   Don't mention it.   Ei kestä.   Eipä kestä.
1   Good afternoon.    Hyvää päivää.    Hyvää iltapäivää.
```

When I debug the application I see that this code:

```
var stream = GetResourceStream(new Uri("/assembly;component/Data/Source.txt", UriKind.Relative));

var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream.Stream);
string line;                

while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    var translation = line.Split('\t');
}
```

Stores into `line`:

```
1\tDon't mention it.\tEi kest�.\tEip� kest�.
1\tGood afternoon.\tHyv�� p�iv��.\tHyv�� iltap�iv��.
```

How do I need to save the file (encoding) and how do I have to read the file in order to get the correct encoding

Comment: When you exported it, what encoding did you use? If you use UTF-8, it should be fine. (I'm not sure where you specify an encoding, and it no doubt depends on the version of Excel, but that's the important bit.)

Comment: I have expored it to UTF-8 as well as to other but non worked :/

Comment: Well if you use UTF-8 for the export, then it *really* should work as-is. How are you determining the problem? Maybe it's how you're displaying it, e.g. with a font which doesn't support everything.

Comment: I have set a breakpoint at the beginig of the while loop and watch what the debuger tells me is inside the line variable...

Comment: Perhaps the problem is just that the debugger can't show the value? Try showing the values within your app as well...

Comment: Have you inspected the tab separated file from Office with a capable text editor (or even hex editor) to determine if the encoding is really UTF-8? That would help you find out if your problem is on the Excel side or not.

Comment: Opened the file just in Notepad and it looked fine. Then I hit the save as button and it turned out it wasn't encoded in UTF-8 but ANSI for some reasone -_- 
Thanks for your help guys :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify Encoding in the StreamReader constructor, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143456.aspx)